# I have 3 fields in a form if the user fills all 3 display selected values from table and if fills 2 specified fields display all values

Tags: php, sql, select

```
if($_POST['sinitial']=="no")
{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE (iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."') OR (iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."')");
?>
```

> I am trying to output names from the table babynames if the user inputs are desired intial >(dinitial) and gender and name category (ncat). But if the user doesnt want only the names >coming into a specific category else he wants to view all the names starting from the >dinitial than how should my query go ?

Comment: currently its giving results -- all names starting with the dinitial and selected gender and when category also selected still showing all the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE (iname like '".$_POST['dinitial']."%' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."') OR (iname like  '".$_POST['dinitial']."%' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."')");

}
```

Comment: yes , you have to if you are trying to get results based on conditions

Comment: If i use this statement it shows me names in specific category but if i dont select category it shows no names. I want it to display all names if the category isnt selected.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."'");

Comment: @Komal : For that, you can change your condition according to your `$_POST['ncat']` values.

Comment: use the following code: $cat='';
if (len($_POST['ncat']==0)
{
 $cat='N';
}

if($cat!='N')
{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."'");
}
else
{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."'");
}

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this way of code..

```
if($_POST['sinitial']=="no")
{
  $condition = "iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."'";

  if(!empty($_POST['ncat'])) 
     $condition .= "AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE $condition");

}
```

Comment: tried ur code its working if ncat selected else showing no results. :(

Comment: I dont know what's wrong with that. Now I edited by answer in different approach. Let's try.

Comment: If `$_POST` value `isset()` then i append the `$condition` otherwise as-usual default `$condition` will be sets on the query.

Comment: if($_POST['sinitial']=="no")
{
{
  if($_POST['ncat']=="0")
  { 
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' ");
  }
  else
 {   
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."' AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."'");
}

}

Comment: okies, Now I got my error, my mistake is to check `isset()` . If you dont mind change `if (!empty($_POST['ncat'])) { ...  }` instead of `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['sinitial']=="no")
{
 $condition = "iname= '".$_POST['dinitial']."' AND gender= '".$_POST['gender']."'";
if(isset($_POST['ncat']) && !empty($_POST['ncat'])) 
 $condition .= "AND ncat= '".$_POST['ncat']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM babyname WHERE $condition");

}
```

Comment: Make sure $_POST['ncat'] is returned empty when user selects no category. You might be using select dropdown for this, use value='' for the first default option.